# Malformed CSS string error when adding dynamic styles using react-jss

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, material-ui, jss

I have CSS styles stored in the state of the component like this:

```
state = {
    value: 1,
    indicatorStyles: {
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(224, 174, 97)",
      }
    },
};
```

and when I try to inject them using the **`injectSheet`** function of `react-jss`:

```js
const CustomTabs = ({classes, children}) => (
      <Tabs 
      value={value} 
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      classes={{root: classes.root, indicator: classes.indicator}}
      >
        {children}
      </Tabs>
    );
const StyledCustomTabs = injectSheet({...indicatorStyles, root: styles.tabsRoot})(CustomTabs);
```

I get the following error in the console:

> Warning: Malformed CSS string "rgb(224, 174, 97)"

I have not found such error on the web just this github closed [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9932).
My goal is to inject dynamic styles (`indicatorStyles`) into the `Tabs` component from **Material UI** library. 
Every time a tab gets selected, the `state` of the component changes and then I want to inject the **updated styles** onto the `Tabs` component.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE!**
The above warning has been fixed thanks to Gabriele's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54042456/7380613) below.

Now the styles are **overwritten** by react **after my custom styles** are applied.

[image]

Is there a way to add CSS rules using react-jss as `!important`?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used react-jss but seeing their docs it looks like you are expected to pass classes and not css properties directly.

So something like

```
indicatorStyles: {
    someStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(224, 174, 97)",
    },
}
```

Comment: it removes the error message but the styles are still not applied

Comment: @CharisTheo `left` and `width` are overriden by the `Tabs` component internally. But they provide the `TabIndicatorProps` for that reason. Pass the `left`, `width` values you want through that property and it should work.